# How to keep source maps on page reload in Chrome

Tags: angular, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I know, that i can upload source maps in chrome devtools by openning interesting file, right clicking
and hitting **add source maps**, then pasting source map url.

It does add a source map indeed. But error in my angular application appears on page load.
So, if i reload page after adding source maps manually, attached source maps is gone.
I unchecked 'disable cache' in network tab - still no use.

I read some articles about angular production debugging and all of them suggest using

```js
sourceMap: {
    hidden: true,
    styles: true,
    scripts: true
}
```

his options in angular.json, yet **hidden: true** is a bad option, since it just doesnt add a comment that loads source maps and source maps themself are being generated and available on server.

**What i want is just to see errors in console that are not from minified *.js file and keep source maps not available publicly.**